# 404 error while accessing youtube api data

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I developed one standalone program to find a video id based upon an assest id.  For this I used service account authentication to generate the access token.  When I passed the access token in my url..it showed 404 not found exception.  Has anybody faced a problem like this?

code:

```
String EmailId = "xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

            //passing Scope
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
              List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
              scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

            final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
            final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

         // Create a listener for automatic refresh OAuthAccessToken
            List<CredentialRefreshListener> list = new ArrayList<CredentialRefreshListener>();
            list.add(new CredentialRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential,
                        TokenResponse tokenResponse) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println(tokenResponse.toPrettyString());

                }

                public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential,
                        TokenErrorResponse tokenErrorResponse)
                        throws IOException {
                    System.err.println("Error: "
                            + tokenErrorResponse.toPrettyString());
                }


            });
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(EmailId)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("xxxxxx.p12"))
            .setRefreshListeners(list)
            .build();
            /*YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT,
                    JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("test1-bd3f7f252932").build();*/
            credential.refreshToken();
```

i got the "token" and now i passed access_token as a parameter in my actual youtube url to get video id: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assetSearch?metadataSearchFields=customId%3Axxxxx&access_token=ya29.9AD4t0HKE-ByFyeXhz7bO6Ha1Ej4ybzrMk2jjlUsvQdRAK-D6wrRr50Sn9KZ01YunTaPRDHpT4JEgQ`

while running this i got exception like :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the code you are running that produces this error.

Comment: Please include the code for that in your question.

Comment: hi denise..i added code here..please check once

Comment: I edited the question for you.  That might be enough information for someone to answer.